# What's wrong with `postion`, I did it correctly?

Tags: python, ursina

```
from ursina import *
#preloads a cube
class Voxel(Button):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(self, position = (0,0,0))(
        parent = scene,
        position = position,
        model = 'cube',
        origin_y = 0.5,
        texture = 'white_cube',
        color = color.white,
        highlight_color = color.lime)

app = Ursina()
#loads a cube
for z in range(8):
    for x in range(8):
        Voxel = Voxel(position = (x,0,z))


app.run()
```

the error is here please help me:

```
File "D:\project\game.py", line 18, in <module>
    Voxel = Voxel(position=(x,0,z)) TypeError: Voxel.__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'position'
```

so what I'm trying to do with this code is make cubes

Comment: Remove `self`. This isn't needed when you call `super()`.__init__()`.

Comment: the code you provided *doesn't even compile*, but I suspect you meant `super().__init__(position = (0,0,0))` instead of `super().__init__(self, position = (0,0,0))` (note, you don't need to pass `self` to `super()`)

Comment: Overloaded methods of a child class do not automatically inherit the signature of their parent. You hardcoded `position = (0,0,0)` when you initialized the super class and did not include a `position` parameter in your own `__init__` method (you wouldn't because this class is using a hardcoded valued). However, when you created an instance, you tried to give a `position` parameter anyway. Either you really did want a position (add it to your `__init__` definition and remove the hardcoded value) or remove the position parameter when you create an instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You likely copy-pasted to the wrong place.

For example, this part of your `super` call `(self, position = (0,0,0))`, was probably intended for your class `__init__` method.

```
def __init__(self, position = (0,0,0)):
```

Moving that makes your class functional.

```
class Voxel(Button):
    def __init__(self, position = (0,0,0)):
        super().__init__(
        parent = scene,
        position = position,
        model = 'cube',
        origin_y = 0.5,
        texture = 'white_cube',
        color = color.white,
        highlight_color = color.lime)
```

You also need to change the name of your class instance at `Voxel = Voxel(position = (x,0,z))` from `Voxel` to something else. As it stands, anything after the first loop would refer to an instance of `Voxel` and not the class itself.

Full working code:

```
from ursina import *
#preloads a cube
class Voxel(Button):
    def __init__(self, position):
        super().__init__(
        parent = scene,
        position = position,
        model = 'cube',
        origin_y = 0.5,
        texture = 'white_cube',
        color = color.white,
        highlight_color = color.lime)

app = Ursina()
#loads a cube
for z in range(8):
    for x in range(8):
        voxel = Voxel(position = (x,0,z))


app.run()
```